# .htaccess URL rewriting - file loaded, but subsequent files don't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm currently trying to use "pretty" URLs instead of using filenames through rewriting in the .htaccess.

This is what I would like to have:

```
site.com/dir/report1    shows   site.com/dir/report.php
site.com/dir/report1/   shows   site.com/dir/report.php
```

I don't want a *redirect* but just the file to be loaded without leaving the pretty URL.

The first one works, but with the all calls to e.g. stylesheets now have "report1/" as base directory and thus can't be found.

Is there any way around this?

Here's my code:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /dir/
RewriteRule    ^report1/?$    report.php    [NC,PT,L]
```

Comment: This is strange: your code does not do any rewriting to `report1/` as base directory (as far as I can see).

Comment: I found the PT tag and it looked like it may or may not do what I hope to achieve - so yes, it may be totally misplaced. And I checked the source of the loaded page, it looked for /dir/report1/css/, since I call for "/css/..." in my code, and the URL is "/dir/report1/"

Comment: Ah, so the `report1` is _not_ the result of the actual rewriting as your question suggests... Then what is the issue? Your pattern certainly will _not_ match the request to `/dir/report1/css/` since you (correctly) anchored the pattern to the string end after the `/`.

Comment: no, it is - I enter ".../dir/report1/", it loads the file (report.php) and in the file, it loads "/css/style.css" - but the full url for the request for the stylesheet is now "site.com/dir/report1/css/style.css", but it should be ".../dir/css/..." as there is no folder "report1"

Comment: Ah, ok, so your issue is that your reference to the css file is wrong! Two options then: 1. do a clean redirection from `/report1/` to `/report1` which is cleaner anyway and will (probably solve the css issue too) or 2. fix your references for assets in the markup you create, for example by using absolute paths, so paths starting with a leading `/`.

Comment: I think option 1 is easier and cleaner - how would I best do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147459/discussion-between-arkascha-and-benjamin-schwalb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from @arkascha I've been able to solve this by redirecting all requests to "/report1/" to "/report1". This is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /dir/
RewriteRule ^report1/$ report1[R=301]
RewriteRule ^report1$   report.php    [L]
```

Comment: I would, but I can't until in two days